# Cuda perform operations atomically

Tags: c++, cuda, mutex, atomic

In my kernel i check for a condition and if it is true i insert the tid into an array.
I need to do the following atomically.

```
if( condition ){
    arr[*index_ptr] = tid;
    (*index_ptr)++
}
```

Basically, i want that no two threads write their tids in the same position in the array.

Is there a simple way to do this? I heard locks were difficult to implement in CUDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cuda library has built in atomic functions. You would be looking for atomicadd()

[Cuda Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomicadd)

This function takes a pointer to an int or float and another int or float (type must match i believe) to add to it. It also conveniently returns the the value of the pointer before the atomic operation.